# After uploaded in the cPanel my Laravel project it's showing the 403 - Error message. How to solve the issue?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cpanel

I have uploaded a Laravel project in cPanel. Project file uploaded in sub folder. I have created the .htaccess file [reference by forums and tutorials] but issue not solve. I am the beginner in Laravel, Please help me.
Folder Path : **example.com->public_html->lrvproject->.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Please do mention samples urls which you are hitting and seeing errors too, thank you.

Comment: For example - https://example.com/lrvproject/
403 - Forbidden
Access to this page is forbidden.

Comment: ok, so when you hitting link example.com/lrvproject from which file(index.php/index.html OR anything else) should serve it? Please confirm on same once.

Comment: I have checked the server.php file. 
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my project working in local pc.

Answer (score 0):

go to the path lrvproject/public  and inside public(folder copy all file and paste outside public folder) here step1 completed.
Step2 . example.com->public_html->lrvproject open index.php file here change the vendor and bootstrap file path like(/../lrvproject/vendor/autoload.php and
/../lrvproject/bootstrap/app.php

Comment: if have any issue contact here

Comment: @Fran I have follow the above steps but after move the folder and file, its showing the 500
SERVER ERROR. How to solve the issue?

Comment: 2021-10-09 05:19:56 UTC [apache][autoindex:error] [pid] [client]: Cannot serve directory /home/sname/www/example.com/public_html/lrvproject/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,Index.html,index.shtml,index.php,Index.php,index.phtml,Index.phtml,index.htm,Index.htm,home.htm,Home.htm,Default.htm,Default.html,default.htm,default.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: I have updated the .httaccess file in root folder. website index page not working, but this url is working in browser. https://www.example.com/lrvproject/public/login. but after loading this page Menu link URL showing is "https://www.example.com/login".

Comment: Dear All can you give me the solution please....

Comment: I have solved the issue. My project running now.